# How to ouput values into one list instead of multiple lists?

Tags: python

I am having a hard time to fix my problem. I made this:

```
def thereyougo():
    """
    The function thereyougo() should return a list with all the numbers from
    1200 upto and including 2399 that are divisible by 12.
    """

    i = range(1200, 2400)
    z = []

    for k in i:
        if k % 12 == 0:
            z.append(k)
            print z

thereyougo()
```

The problem is, that I get a whole bunch of lists, but I want just one.

For example, this is the output I get:

```
[1200]
[1200, 1212]
[1200, 1212, 1224]
[1200, 1212, 1224, 1236]
```

While I want `[1200, 1212, 1224... ]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are printing z in scope of if ,move it out of scope of if man

Comment: You're printing lists, not returning them.  To return them, you would use the `return` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `un-indent` the `print`:

```
for k in i:
    if k % 12 == 0:
        z.append(k)
print z
```

---

Note that you could do this more efficiently  by using the `step` param of the `range()` generator. This would allow you to get every `12th` number which would, by definition, be every `multiple`.

Using the above, you could reduce your function down to:

```
def thereyougo():
    print list(range(1200, 2400, 12))
```

which, when called, would give:

```
[1200, 1212, 1224, 1236, 1248, 1260, 1272, 1284, 1296, 1308, 1320, 1332, 1344, 1356, 1368, 1380, 1392, 1404, 1416, 1428, 1440, 1452, 1464, 1476, 1488, 1500, 1512, 1524, 1536, 1548, 1560, 1572, 1584, 1596, 1608, 1620, 1632, 1644, 1656, 1668, 1680, 1692, 1704, 1716, 1728, 1740, 1752, 1764, 1776, 1788, 1800, 1812, 1824, 1836, 1848, 1860, 1872, 1884, 1896, 1908, 1920, 1932, 1944, 1956, 1968, 1980, 1992, 2004, 2016, 2028, 2040, 2052, 2064, 2076, 2088, 2100, 2112, 2124, 2136, 2148, 2160, 2172, 2184, 2196, 2208, 2220, 2232, 2244, 2256, 2268, 2280, 2292, 2304, 2316, 2328, 2340, 2352, 2364, 2376, 2388]
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe! Can you explain to me why I should indent the print? I didn't catch that one. I mean, how does it know it can pass the bunch to z, if it's not in the for loop?

Comment: @Siyah So anything inside the `for-loop` (as in on its indentation level), will be ran each time it `loop`, so for every `multiple` of `12` in this case. So therefore, if you `print z` there then it will be printed on every loop so many times. However, the `z` `list` still exists after the `for-loop` completes, so you can just `print` it there once everything has been added to it. Please remember to `accept` thank you! **:)**

Comment: Thanks, Joe! Appreciated.